# Creaating a new Key Value dict from previous dict

Tags: dictionary, erlang

So, I have a dict called `conquered`. The porpouse of this dict is store a Key, Value dict of lists to use concurrency on a divide and conquer method to search for values.

The code goes on:

```erl
-module(divide).
-export([divide_the_cache/4]).

-define(divided, dict:new()).

divide_the_cache(cache, divided, thread_index, acc) ->
    case length(cache) =< acc of
        thread_index ->
            l = lists:merge([lists:nth(thread_index, divided)], [lists:nth(acc, cached)]);
            conquered = dict:append(thread_index, l, dict:from_list(divided));
            thread_index = if length(l) == 24 -> thread_index = thread_index + 1, end;

            divide_the_cache(cache, conquered, thread_index, acc+1);
    end.
```

I'm getting:

```
divide.erl:10:69: syntax error before: ';'
%   10|             conquered = dict:append(thread_index, l, dict:from_list(divided));
%     |
```

When I'm not using function composition on dict:append I get:

```
divide.erl:10:36: syntax error before: ';'
%   10|             d_list = dict:from_list(divided);
%     |                                             ^
```

I've already consulted the documentation and sites across the web, but could encounter an example(except to work with dict:from_list) and follow the docs trying on the repl.

What could going wrong? What is the best way to achieve what I need?

Thanks in advance, Lukas.

Comment: Are you using lower cased variable names in Erlang?

Answer (score 1):

Your code have multiple issues, most of them syntactic ones. Let me try to rewrite it in a more *syntactically correct* way. Then, you'll need to fix whatever semantics you want to give to it on your own:

```erlang
-module(divide).
-export([divide_the_cache/4]).

divide_the_cache(Cache, Divided, ThreadIndex, Acc)
  when length(Cache) =< Acc ->
    L = lists:merge(
          [lists:nth(ThreadIndex, dict:to_list(Divided))],
          [lists:nth(Acc, Cache)]
        ),
    Conquered = dict:append(ThreadIndex, L, Divided),
    NewThreadIndex =
      case length(L) of
        24 -> ThreadIndex + 1;
        _ -> ThreadIndex
      end,
    divide_the_cache(Cache, Conquered, NewThreadIndex, Acc+1).
```

What I changed:

1. `-define` in Erlang is for macros and you were not using the `?divided` macro anywhere.
2. Variables in Erlang start in uppercase.
3. `case length(Cache) =< Acc of ThreadIndex ->` made no sense to me, so I replaced it with a guard (`when length(Cache) =< Acc`).
4. `Divided` should be either a dict or a list but it's treated as a list first and a dict later… so I decided that it's always a dict and thus, for `lists:nth/2`, I used `dict:to_list/1`.
5. In Erlang, expressions end in `,` (not `;`) and functions end in `.`.
6. You shouldn't write else-less if's in Erlang, so I turned your `if` into a `case` statement.
7. Variables in Erlang can't be re-bound, that's why I introduced `NewThreadIndex`.